# Repetir laço enquanto o usuário escolher a opção de continuar

Tags: java

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em Java e após calcular tudo que o usuário pediu, eu preciso que ele informe a seguinte mensagem: `"Deseja calcular novamente? S/N"`.

Estou usando o `do`/`while` mas não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar. Segue abaixo o código:

```java
package beta;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author lab
 */
public class Beta {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
        String escolha ;
        double raio , area , base , altura , raioM , diagonalm , diagonalM ;
        String volta;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);


        do{

            System.out.println("O que deseja Calcular? ");
                    System.out.println("1. Circulo");
                    System.out.println("2. Triângulo");
                    System.out.println("3. Trapézio");
                    System.out.println("4. Retângulo");
                    System.out.println("5. Corda Circular");
                    System.out.println("6. Diagonal do Losango");
                    System.out.println("7. Sair");
            escolha = obj.nextLine();


switch(escolha){

             case "1":
                System.out.println("Qual o raio do Círculo? ");
                raio = obj.nextDouble();
                area = 3.14 * (raio*raio);
                System.out.println("A área do Círculo é " + area);
             break;

             case "2":
                System.out.println("Qual a base do Triângulo: ");
                base = obj.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Qual a Altura do Triângulo: ");
                altura = obj.nextDouble();
                area = (base*altura)/2;
                System.out.println("A área do Triângulo é " + area);
             break;

             case "3":
                System.out.println("Qual a base do Trapézio: ");
                base = obj.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Qual a Altura do Trapézio: ");
                altura = obj.nextDouble();
                area = (base+base)*altura/2;
                System.out.println("A área do Trapézio é " + area);
             break;
             case "4":
                System.out.println("Qual a base do Retângulo: ");
                base = obj.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Qual a Altura do Retângulo: ");
                altura = obj.nextDouble();
                area = base*altura;
                System.out.println("A área do Retângulo é " + area);
             break; 
             case "5":
                System.out.println("Qual o maior raio da Corda Circular: ");
                raio = obj.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Qual o menor raio da Corda Circular: ");
                raioM = obj.nextDouble();
                area = raio*raio - raioM*raioM;
                System.out.println("A área da corda circular é Pi " + area);
             break;
             case "6":
                System.out.println("Qual a maior Diagonal do Losango: ");
                diagonalM = obj.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Qual a menor Diagonal do Losango: ");
                diagonalm = obj.nextDouble();
                area = (diagonalM*diagonalm)/2;
                System.out.println("A área do Losango é " + area);
             break;                          

           }   
      escolha = scanner.next();     
    } while(escolha.equalsIgnoreCase("Deseja calcular novamente? S/N"));            

    } // fim main

} // fim classe
```

Comment: Você está perguntando se o que foi lido é idêntico à `"Deseja calcular novamente? S/N"` (ignorando diferença de caixa alta/baixa), o que não faz sentido

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, não tem porque criar dois `Scanner`'s, já que ambos estão lendo do `System.in`. Usar apenas um é o suficiente (e chamar um deles de `obj` não ajuda muito, [dê nomes melhores para as variáveis](https://hackernoon.com/the-art-of-naming-variables-52f44de00aad)).

Outro ponto é que a `escolha` deve ser comparada com `"s"`, e não com o texto `"Deseja calcular novamente? S/N"`.

Outro detalhe é que métodos como `nextDouble()` não consomem a quebra de linha (no caso, o <kbd>ENTER</kbd>), então você [deve chamar `nextLine()` logo depois](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13102066), caso contrário a próxima chamada de `nextLine()` consumirá apenas a quebra de linha, deixando a `escolha` vazia.

Faltou também verificar se a opção é "7", e sair do `while` neste caso. E também removi a variável `volta`, pois ela não é usada no código.

Enfim, o código ficaria assim:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String escolha;
double raio, area, base, altura, raioM, diagonalm, diagonalM;

do {
    System.out.println("O que deseja Calcular? ");
    System.out.println("1. Circulo");
    System.out.println("2. Triângulo");
    System.out.println("3. Trapézio");
    System.out.println("4. Retângulo");
    System.out.println("5. Corda Circular");
    System.out.println("6. Diagonal do Losango");
    System.out.println("7. Sair");
    escolha = scanner.nextLine();
    // se for 7, sai do while
    if ("7".equals(escolha))
        break;

    switch (escolha) {
        case "1":
            System.out.println("Qual o raio do Círculo? ");
            raio = scanner.nextDouble(); // use o "scanner", não mais o "obj"
         .... dentro do switch é igual
    }

    scanner.nextLine(); // consumir a quebra de linha, pois nextDouble() não a consome
    System.out.println("Deseja calcular novamente? S/N");
} while (scanner.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("s")); // nem precisa guardar o resultado de nextLine() em uma variável, pode comparar direto
```

---

Mas se as opções só podem ser números, então por que não usar `nextInt()` para lê-las?

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int escolha;
double raio, area, base, altura, raioM, diagonalm, diagonalM;

do {
    System.out.println("O que deseja Calcular? ");
    System.out.println("1. Circulo");
    System.out.println("2. Triângulo");
    System.out.println("3. Trapézio");
    System.out.println("4. Retângulo");
    System.out.println("5. Corda Circular");
    System.out.println("6. Diagonal do Losango");
    System.out.println("7. Sair");
    escolha = scanner.nextInt();
    if (escolha == 7)
        break;

    switch (escolha) {
        case 1:
           ....

        case 2:
           ....

           ....etc

        default: // pequena "firula"
            System.out.printf("Opçao inválida: %d\n", escolha);
    }

    scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Deseja calcular novamente? S/N");
} while (scanner.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("s"));
```

Comment: Estava comentando no momento que você publicou a resposta ;-)

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado E eu ia comentar que estava respondendo no momento em que vc comentou :-)

Comment: E eu estava respondendo, saí pra jantar, voltei, respondi e vi que vocês já estavam comentando esta resposta =(

Comment: Realizei todas as alterações que indicou amigo e ficou exatamente como eu queria, muito obrigado, de coração mesmo, já não aguentava quebrar a cabeça com esse código mais, sou iniciante em Java ainda! kkk Obrigado!

Comment: @LuísFillipeMagalhães Se uma das respostas resolveu o seu problema, vc pode escolher a que melhor resolveu e aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. E quando tiver 15 pontos, [**vc também poderá votar**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) em todas as respostas que achou úteis.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode matar essa charada olhando a condição do while, na sua condição **"(escolha.equalsIgnoreCase("Deseja calcular novamente? S/N"));" você está comparando se o usuário escreveu "Deseja calcular novamente? S/N"** ignorando o tamanho das letras, ou seja, para apresentar novamente o menu no fim de uma de suas opções(considerando que o usuário tenha digitado um número no intervalo [1,7]) o usuário teria que escrever "Deseja calcular novamente? S/N".

Provavelmente o que você quer pode ser feito trocando

```
escolha = scanner.next();     
} while(escolha.equalsIgnoreCase("Deseja calcular novamente? S/N"));
```

por

```
System.out.println("Deseja calcular novamente? S/N");
escolha = scanner.next();  

} while(escolha.equalsIgnoreCase("s"));
```

**Obs**: Há trechos no seu código que podem ser melhorados, tentei focar apenas no cerne da pergunta.

Comment: Vou testar agora o programa com as modificações, sobre as melhoras em outros trechos, estou iniciante em java ainda kkkk menos de 2 semanas aprendendo, mas já gostei bastante da linguagem!

Comment: Sua dica foi bem útil amigo, mas ainda estou com um problema, apos realizar os cálculos, o progama sugere a pergunta "Deseja calcular novamente? S/N" conforme o previsto, mas quando seleciono o "S" ele me apresenta as opções novamente mas antes que eu responda o que desejo calcular ele já me faz a pergunta "Deseja calcular novamente? S/N" novamente.. Alguma ideia de como poso solucionar isso? Mas muito obrigado já por estar me ajudando!

Comment: Para resolver este problema você deve trocar **escolha = obj.nextLine();** por **escolha = obj.next();**, todavia seria melhor se você já utiliza-se o nextInt() e trocasse os cases do switch para inteiro assim como o  @hkotsubo exemplificou. Fico agradecido por ter sido útil =)